# How to change mysql8.0 default port

Tags: server

I have installed MySQL 8.0 on Ubuntu 18.0. I want to change default port 3306 to xxxxx.

I need help how to do that i am not able to see any comments on /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file add these lines:

```
[mysqld]
port = xxxxx
```

Save it and then run:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```